# Site not being responsive on Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, heroku

I am trying to host my site in GoDaddy via Heroku,the site in my local and also in Heroku is responsive and working fine, but when check on the final one from GoDaddy. It is not responsive and neither the title and logo are working when I checked the code it is using an iframe to redirect the site from Heroku. Can anyone help me out with how to solve this problem Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're using GoDaddy's "forward my domain" with [their "masking"](https://www.godaddy.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-domain-forwarding-and-masking-32147) feature. That's a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, what are the alternatives of this to host on godaddy from heroku, without need to verify the card on heroku.

Comment: Why are you resistant to verifying your Heroku account?

Comment: Actually I don't have a valid card, they accept visa or master-card which i don't have.

Comment: Consider a different host, then.

Comment: If somehow I managed to get and verify a valid card, so hosting from heroku using custom domain will gonna solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes, if you set it up correctly; Heroku will provide you with a DNS CNAME record to put in place at GoDaddy.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.